# PhoneGap (Build) & SignalR, works everywhere except when actually installed on device with vague error

Tags: asp.net, mobile, signalr, phonegap

I have created a SignalR server, a web client, and a mobile application built with PhoneGap Build. When I launch the PhoneGap application with lite-server, PhoneGap CLI, or the PhoneGap Desktop Application the SignalR works flawlessly between the web client and the PhoneGap application. This includes using the PhoneGap mobile application to connect to the PhoneGap Desktop application. The only time it fails is when I build it with PhoneGap Build and install the APK on the device. I have no explanation for this error.

I have handled CORS through the WEB.CONFIG of the server. It is a plain ASP.NET application that just has an OWIN startup file to configure SignalR and a Hub class.

```
 <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE, TOKEN" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="false"/>
      </customHeaders>  
    </httpProtocol>
 </system.webServer>
```

The frustrating part is that the error that is produced when $.connection.hub.start fails is just **"Error: Error during negotiation request"**

When 'deviceready' event triggers I call initiateSignalR()

```
var appConfig = {
    'serverUrl': "http://wolf-signalrserver.azurewebsites.net"
}

var initiateSignalR = function(){
    if ($.signalR) {

    }

    var username = prompt("username");
    var success = `
                <div class ="serverMessage">
                    <span>--- WELCOME, ${username} ---</span>
                </div>
            `
    $('#chatbox').append(success)




        $.connection.hub.logging = true
        $.connection.hub.qs = { 'username': username }
        $.connection.hub.url = appConfig.serverUrl + "/signalr";
        var chatHub = $.connection.chatHub

        chatHub.client.broadcastMessage = function (name, message) {
            console.log("Data Incoming ---- Name: " + name + " Message: " + message);
            var message = `
                <div class="row">
                    <span class="col-sm-2">${name}:</span> 
                    <span class="col-sm-9"> ${message}</span>
                </div>
            `
            $('#chatbox').append(message)
        }


        $('#messageButton').on('click', function () {
            chatHub.server.send(username, $('#messageBox').val())
        })
        $('#messageForm').on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            chatHub.server.send(username, $('#messageBox').val())
        })

        $.connection.hub.start({ withCredentials: false, jsonp: true })
            .done(function () {
                console.log("Connected successfully to SignalR");
                var success = `
                    <div class ="serverMessage">
                        <span>--- Successfully connected to the server ---</span>
                    </div>
                `
                $('#chatbox').append(success)
            })
            .fail(function (err) {
                console.log("Unable to connect to SignalR")
                alert(err);
            })
}
```

I have a git repo of this here: https://github.com/PhilWolf91/SignalR

I realize there are tons of questions here with this, but none of them have a detailed answer to how they fixed it.
Ex: [SignalR .Net Client fails with 500 server error on device, on simulator works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686191/signalr-net-client-fails-with-500-server-error-on-device-on-simulator-works-fi)

Answer (score 0):

OK. I'm a giant idiot. When I was cleaning up the Config.Xml I removed the network permission AND the default White List plugin.

```
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
<gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
```

Full functional config for this project

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.wolf.signalrphonegap" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0">
    <name>SignalRPhoneGap</name>
    <description>
        Hello World sample application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="phillip.wolf91@gmail.com" href="http://phillipwolf91.wordpress.com">
        Wolf Software
    </author>

    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/network" />
    <gap:plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" source="npm" />
    <content src="index.html" />
    <preference name="DisallowOverscroll" value="true" />
    <preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="14" />
    <platform name="android">
    </platform>    
    <access origin="*" />
    <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
    <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
    <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
    <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
    <platform name="android">
        <allow-intent href="market:*" />
    </platform>

</widget>
```

I now have SignalR working between the Server, Web Client, and PhoneGap app installed on the device