# SignalR .NET client (xamarin) difference in debug and release

Tags: xamarin.android, release, signalr.client

I have Xamarin Android App with PCL shared library where SignalR communication established.

In debug mode it's working.
See IIS trace:

> 2017-06-24 09:40:50 192.168.1.220 GET
>   /signalr/negotiate+clientProtocol=1.4&connectionData=[{}]&UserId=1137158
>   - 80 - 192.168.1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+10.0;+Win64;+x64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/58.0.3029.110+Safari/537.36
>   - 301 0 0 31

In release mode it's NOT working:

> 2017-06-24 09:53:54 192.168.1.220 GET /signalr/negotiate
>   clientProtocol=1.5&connectionData=[%7B%7D]&UserId=1137158 80 -
>   192.168.1.1 SignalR.Client.NetStandard/2.2.2.0+(Unknown+OS) - 500 0 0 31

And Server-side SignalR code throwing exception somewhere internally (spotted in logs).

It could be fixed by setting '**Linkage**' to '**None**' in Android compilation options, but i'm not sure if that's correct way to solve this.
(found here [SignalR .Net Client fails with 500 server error on device, on simulator works fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32686191/signalr-net-client-fails-with-500-server-error-on-device-on-simulator-works-fi))

Comment: Seems like a different DLL is chosen for some reason when compiling for release.

Comment: if I only know which one to skip for linking. Because app becomes too heavy when Linking = None